# Why is the Spring Security REST Plugin not compatible with JDK 1.6?

Tags: rest, grails, dependency-management, jwt

According to [the official Grails docs](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.4.2/guide/gettingStarted.html#requirements), Grails 2.4.2 works with JDK 1.6. As far as a I'm concerned, this means I can run all plugins that work with Grails 2.4.2 in an execution environment that runs on JDK 1.6.

However, as I tried to deploy the war file of my Grails application to a Glassfish v3.1 that runs on JDK 1.6, I experienced issues with dependencies that were not JDK 1.6 compliant:

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: WEB9032: Class   com.nimbusds.jwt.JWT has unsupported major or minor version numbers, which are greater than those found in the Java Runtime Env
ironment version 1.6.0_07
    at       org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:948)
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1485)
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1368)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:319)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2427)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1791)
    ... 55 more
```

After running `dependency-report`, I found out that the issue was caused by a dependency of the Spring Security REST Plugin:

```
+--- org.grails.plugins:spring-security-rest:1.5.1
|    \--- net.spy:spymemcached:2.11.6
|    \--- com.google.guava:guava-io:r03
|         \--- com.google.guava:guava-annotations:r03
|         \--- com.google.guava:guava-base:r03
|    \--- org.pac4j:pac4j-core:1.6.0
|    \--- org.pac4j:pac4j-oauth:1.6.0
|         \--- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.1
|         \--- org.scribe:scribe:1.3.6
|         \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.0.6
|              \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.0.6
|              \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.0.6
|    \--- com.nimbusds:nimbus-jose-jwt:3.9
|         \--- net.jcip:jcip-annotations:1.0
|         \--- net.minidev:json-smart:1.1.1
|         \--- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:1.51
|         \--- commons-io:commons-io:2.4
```

The class causing the issue, `com.nimbusds.jwt.JWT` is part of the artifact `nimbus-jose-jwt`, which the Spring Security REST Plugin depends on.

I feel like this Plugin should be JDK 1.6 compliant, since on the plugin's page it says **Grails version: 2.0 > ***. This is very misleading, as I spent quite some time developing and now I realize that I cannot even deploy it to production. Shouldn't it say **Grails version: 3.0 > ***, or am I misunderstanding something here?

Comment: I'm the author of `spring-security-rest`. Honestly, I wasn't aware of that requirement of Nimbus, that's why is not advertised. On the other hand, using Java 6, when not only it but also Java 7 is already unsupported, feels odd to me. Anyway, I will mention in the documentation the minimum version requirement.

Comment: Thank you for taking you time commenting this. I am honestly surprised about this fast reply and glad that this will be documented now, as I love your plugin and hated the fact that I could not use it in production.

It worked like a charm on JDK 1.7. Followed the documentation and did not have to configure anything except the filter chain. Great plugin, did not mean to criticise anything but the undocumented JDK issue!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the reason why [Nimbus JOSE+JWT](http://connect2id.com/products/nimbus-jose-jwt) (which is used by Spring Security Core plugin) requires Java 7+ is due to the fact lesser versions of Java don't support the same cryptography. Take a look through their website and you will see the minimum requirements:

> The Nimbus JOSE + JWT library requires Java 7+ and has minimal
>   dependencies.

Your assumption that just because the plugin supports Grails 2.0+ means that it also supports JDK 1.6 is just that, an assumption, and obviously incorrect. There is no requirement that Grails plugins target a specific Java compatibility level.

The fact your development was done without using the minimum target version of Java used in your production environment is the real culprit. You should always develop and test with the minimum requirements of your target production environment.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification. I was unsure if it is regular practice not to mention compliance problems with JDK versions that are considered compliant with Grails. That is why I was asking if I misunderstand in the first place. To me it still seems strange. I run a Grails application on an execution environment that is specified as compliant for the chosen Grails version. Then I install a plugin that is specified as compliant with that version. Should it not be pointed out in some sort of warning that I may run into issues with certain execution environments?

Comment: I know I should have used JDK 1.6_07 in the first place; however, I was using another work station at that time. I'm not saying this is not my fault, just that some hours of work could have been spared by pointing out issues with common JDKs. After all, if I had read about the plugin for some time, tried to install it for some time and then ran into the compliance issues locally, I would have still lost precious time in that process.

Comment: I agree, the more information that can be provided about minimum requirements should be, and I know if you reached out to the author of the plugin I am sure they would be happy to include this information for future users. I'm sorry you lost precious time, but you have learned a few things along the way. 1. Version of Grails does not indicate in any way the JDK requirements and 2. Always develop using the minimum JDK that will be used in production. I'm glad I was able to clear up your confusion about the Grails version and JDK requirements.

Comment: That is certainly true. without having to solve issues like that, I would not be where I am today. I am glad, though, that this question pops up first when I search "spring security rest nimbus" on google. This may help lazy people like me in the future that do not further inspect all dependencies before installing a plugin :)